# SwiftUI serial DispatchQueue in background thread

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

In SwiftUI I have a `List()` with the name and status of 3 tasks:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let tasks = [TaskOne(), TaskTwo(), TaskThree()]

    var body: some View {
        List(tasks) { task in
          Text(task.name)
          Text(task.httpCode) // TODO
        }

        Button(action: { runTasks() }) {
            Text("Run tasks")
        }
    }

    private func runTasks() {
        for task in tasks {
             task.run()
             // 1. Pass the output to the next task once finished
             // 2. Update the status of the task in the List
        }
    }
}
```

Each task does http request but can have custom logic and they need to be separate:

```swift
protocol ExecutableTask {
    var name: String { get set }
    var httpCode: Int? { get set }

    func execute(input: String) -> String
}

struct TaskOne: ExecutableTask {
    var name = "one"
    var httpCode: Int?

    func execute(input: String) -> String {
        // task specific logic here
        // TODO: Perform HTTP call to "http://example.com/\(input)" and update httpCode in the List
        return "first"
    }
}

struct TaskTwo: ExecutableTask {
    var name = "two"
    var httpCode: Int?

    func execute(input: String) -> String {
        // task specific logic here
        // TODO: Perform HTTP call to "http://example.com/\(input)" and update httpCode in the List
        return "second"
    }
}

struct TaskThree: ExecutableTask {
    var name = "three"
    var httpCode: Int?

    func execute(input: String) -> String {
        // task specific logic here
        // TODO: Perform HTTP call to "http://example.com/\(input)" and update httpCode in the List
        return "third"
    }
}
```

How can I execute all of the serially in a background thread, passing the output from one to another and updating status in the `List`?

I suppose I need to update each row in the table by using `@State` and perform task execution using `DispatchQueue`. However I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: You can use the "traditional" approach - each task accepts a completion handler and you invoke the next task from the completion handler.  If you are using SwiftUI then the more "modern" approach is to use `Combine` and create a pipeline that performs the work.

Comment: Either way you don't want `@State`. You need `ExecutableTask` to be a `class` not a `struct` and to conform to `ObservableObject`.  You can then have `@Published var httpCode` and bind to `$task.httpCode` in your list row.